# Ctrl-Shift-number key combination has stopped working for a few numbers

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

A web app I use uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> through <kbd>9</kbd> as particular keyboard shortcuts. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> has never worked for me, but <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> always did. I rarely had to use <kbd>0</kbd>, so I just sort of ignored it. However, suddenly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, +<kbd>3</kbd>, and +<kbd>8</kbd> have also stopped working - possibly right after upgrading to the latest version of Windows 10; I'm not exactly sure on the timing of when I updated and started noticing this behavior. This is happening across multiple browsers, and it's not the app itself that's having issues as going to keycode.info and checking to see which key presses are being registered confirms that those four specific number keys are not being registered when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> are also being held down.

I also doubt it's a hardware issue as I used AutoHotkey to map that specific sequence to my function keys and I'm getting the exact same behavior as when actually physically pressing all three keys. It seems like Windows itself must be overriding that key sequence or something, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> combination(s) are often used
for switching input languages.

To check and modify:

- Start *Settings*
- Click *Devices > Typing*
- Click *Advanced keyboard settings*
- Click *Input language hot keys*
- Select a combination and click *Change Key Sequence...*
- If you see your key combination, to disable set both radio buttons to
  "Not Assigned", or set it to any other sequence
- Click OK.

Comment: I tried this and it had no effect, unfortunately

Comment: Were these shortcuts used among the language hot keys?

Comment: For the Between input languages action Control + Shift was assigned to Switch Input Language, and I selected the Not Assigned radio button and saved. The only other action available was To English, and that was not enabled. If it was, Ctrl + 0 was the default shortcut, but it was and is grayed out

Comment: I tested these keys in Windows and they do nothing. However, for Firefox and Chrome they now scroll the page. I think your problem is the browsers, not Windows.

Comment: I've tried this in both Chrome, Opera, Firefox, and Edge on this PC and am having the same results. It works as expected on a second computer I tried it on in Chrome, and no other users are complaining of this problem, so I don't think it's the browsers. When I get some time tonight, I'm going to try resetting Windows and see if that does it since this really is killing years of built up muscle memory for me. I wish it wasn't a proprietary work app so I could link it.

Comment: Yeah, resetting Windows fixed it, and even the Control + Shift + 0 works now. Not a very elegant solution, but it wouldn't affect me much to reset everything, so it works

Comment: I actually don't know what version I was beforehand, but now it's 1809. I'll have to update Windows to the latest version and see if it pops up again.

Comment: OK, it has something to do with the 1903 update because I just upgraded and the exact same behavior started happening.

Comment: I just sent them feedback and will roll back in the meantime

Comment: See also [How to block the Windows 10 May 2019 Update, version 1903, from installing](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3232632/how-to-block-the-windows-10-may-2019-update-version-1903-from-installing.html).

Comment: this worked for me. For some reason Ctrl + Shift + 2 was being used to change to my 2nd language even though the setting said that there was "none" shortcut set to it. The fix was to set something to it, then change it back to none.

Comment: I can confirm that the above steps work, but sometimes you need to do as @JorgeLuque suggested and assign your language bar options to some key, then unbind them, to fix Ctrl+Shift+0. This seems to be a bug introduced in later versions of Windows 10 where the settings show no keybinding, but in fact it is listening to the keys anyway.

Comment: I was trying to use Ctrl+Shift+1 in my app I am building and it was driving me crazy that it wouldn't work.